# ASP.NET MVC routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need help with this route map

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog_Archive", 
                "Blog/Archive/{year}/{month}/{day}",
                new { 
                      controller = "Blog",
                      action = "archive",
                      year = "",
                      month = "",
                      day = "",
                      page = 0
                    });
```

When I call **http://localhost:5060/blog/Archive/2008/11**, it picks up the year and month and sends it to the controller. But when I try **http://localhost:5060/blog/Archive/2008**
it sends it to the controller but the year parameter is null and so are all the other parameters.

Comment: Xenph Yan thanks for the spellcheck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have any other Route for Blog/Archive/{something}?

Use the [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see which route actually gets hit, most likely it's not hitting that route.

Comment: Highly recommend the Routing Debugger!

Answer (score 0):

Subnus,
I noticed in your code that you have routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
I don't think this is required with MVC 1.0 right because the period is no longer ignored correct?

Comment: this question was i regard to the Beta 2 of asp.net mvc and not the now release version of mvc and the question was not about the ignored route